# AOT Compilation issue getting Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'TranslateModule'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

I am facing issue while (npm run ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json) compiling AOT. Unable to understand even 
I tried replacing

```
TranslateModule.forRoot(TRANSLATE_LOADER)

export function translateLoader(http: Http): TranslateStaticLoader {
return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, (window as any).rest + "textmodules", ".json");
};
const TRANSLATE_LOADER: any = {
provide: TranslateLoader,
useFactory: translateLoader,
deps: [Http]
}
```

insted of

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
   provide: TranslateLoader,
   useFactory: (http: Http): TranslateStaticLoader => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, (window as any).rest + "textmodules", ".json"),
   deps: [Http]
  })
```

but still getting

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'TranslateModule', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /home/retacc/dev/src/sbb-ri-erepko/retacc.sbb.ri.erepko.main/src/integrated-workshop/src/app/app.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   /home/retacc/dev/src/sbb-ri-erepko/retacc.sbb.ri.erepko.main/src/integrated-workshop/src/app/app.module.ts

my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ErrorHandler } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Http, HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { combineReducers, StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { ActionReducer } from "@ngrx/store";
import { compose } from "@ngrx/core/compose";
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { TranslateStaticLoader, TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";
// import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  

import { JobSearchService } from "./job-selection-search/job-search/job-search.service";
import { ContextHttp } from "./common/component/context-http/context-http.service";
import { IntegratedWorkshopComponent } from "./integratedWorkshop.component";
import { APP_ROUTES } from "./app.routes";
import { ScrollTopComponent } from "./common/component/scroll-top/scroll-top.component";
import { IWErrorHandler } from "./common/error-handler/iw-error-handler";
import { SharedModule } from "./common/shared.module";
import { CommonModule } from "./common/common.module"
import { VehicleInformationModule } from "./vehicle-information/vehicle-information.module";
import { CustomerConcernModule } from "./customer-concern/customer-concern.module";
import { LocalContentModule } from "./local-content/local-content.module";
import { JobSelectionSearchComponentModule } from "./job-selection-search/job-selection-search.component.module";
import { JobContentModule } from "./job-content/job-content.module";
import { JOB } from "./store/reducer/job.reducer";
import { JOB_SELECTION } from "./store/reducer/job-selection.reducer";
import { CustomBack } from "./common/util/custom.back";
import { HEADER_CONTENT } from "./store/reducer/header-content.reducer";
import { ShortTestModule } from "./short-test/short-test.module";
import { ASSOCIATED_DOCUMENTS } from "./store/reducer/associated-documents.reducer";

export function translateLoader(http: Http): TranslateStaticLoader {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, (window as any).rest + "textmodules", ".json");
};

const developmentReducer: ActionReducer<any> = compose(
                combineReducers
)({ JOB_SELECTION, JOB, HEADER_CONTENT, ASSOCIATED_DOCUMENTS });

export function reducer(state: any, action: any) {
    return developmentReducer(state, action);
};

const TRANSLATE_LOADER: any = {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: translateLoader,
    deps: [Http]
}

// export { IntegratedWorkshopComponent, ScrollTopComponent };

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // angular modules
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        // no forms module, import it in feature modules
        // according to ng documentation import http module ONLY in app module (has providers)
        HttpModule,
        StoreModule.provideStore(reducer),
        RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true }),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(TRANSLATE_LOADER),
        // lib modules
        // TranslateModule.forRoot({
        //  provide: TranslateLoader,
        //  useFactory: (http: Http): TranslateStaticLoader => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, (window as any).rest + "textmodules", ".json"),
        //  deps: [Http]
        // }),
        SharedModule,
        // // app-common and app-shared modules with additional providers
        CommonModule.forRoot(),
        // // app-feature modules
        // CommonModule,
        JobContentModule,
        JobSelectionSearchComponentModule,
        VehicleInformationModule,
        CustomerConcernModule,
        LocalContentModule,
        ShortTestModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        IntegratedWorkshopComponent,
        ScrollTopComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        // provideStore(
        //  compose(
        //      combineReducers
        //  )({ JOB_SELECTION, JOB, HEADER_CONTENT, ASSOCIATED_DOCUMENTS })
        // ),
        TranslateService, { provide: TranslateLoader, useFactory: translateLoader, deps: [Http] },
        JobSearchService,
        ContextHttp,
        CustomBack,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IWErrorHandler }
    ],
    bootstrap: [IntegratedWorkshopComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using lamda function here:
`useFactory: (http: Http): TranslateStaticLoader => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, (window as any).rest + "textmodules", ".json")`

Replace your code with this one.

```
export function translateLoader(http: Http): TranslateStaticLoader {

     return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, (window as any).rest + "textmodules", ".json");

};

TranslateModule.forRoot({
   provide: TranslateLoader,
   useFactory: (translateLoader),
   deps: [Http]
})
```

Comment: Did you remove const TRANSLATE_LOADER?

Comment: If it still didn't work, try removing TranslateService from provider or add TranslateModule in exports.